# issue raised when adding a rectangle to the uiview

Tags: ios, core-graphics, drawrect

I am drawing an rectangle using tutorial at [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D)

FlagClass.m

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150, 150);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 200);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50, 150);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);

        CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

    @end
```

Then I am adding this view to another view like below

```
-(IBAction)drawRectangle {
    FlagClass     *flag     =   [[FlagClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 100.0, 80, 40)];

    [self.view addSubview:flag];

}
```

After clicking on the button, what I got is

[image]

My question :

1. These coordinate of my rectangle is (20,100,80,40).What are the numbers in `drawRect` method
2. Why I am just getting a black rectangle instead of the blue one with defined coordinates in `drawRect`

Please help if you have any ideas about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the dimensions of your view (the `FlagClass` instance), all of your drawing is going on outside of the visible bounds (the view is "clipping" the blue rectangle). The black rectangle you're seeing is the default background fill of UIView.

To get what you want, you could adjust the frame of your subview so it's large enough to contain the stroked path. Or change the coordinates you're using to draw; those are the numbers in the calls to `CGContextAddLineToPoint`. Here's one way to at least see what you're doing (while removing the black background):

```
FlagClass *flag = [[FlagClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 100.0, 250, 250)];
flag.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:flag];
```

By changing the width and height of the subview (the 3rd and 4th parameters to `CGRectMake`), the subview becomes large enough to contain the square being drawn.